# How to verify a datatype mismatch? (not=== false)

Tags: php, syntax, logical-operators

What's the opposite of triple equals matching in PHP?

```
$mail_01 = filter_var($mail_01, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
if($mail !== false){
    echo "Email address required";
}
```

Is the `!==` usage correct?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. See the [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, `!==` is correct.  From the manual:

> $a !== $b     Not identical
>   TRUE if $a is not equal to $b, or they are not of the same type. 
>   (introduced in PHP 4)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that's correct. `a !== b` is logically equivalent to `!(a === b)`.